# How to create a utility function for XMLHttpRequest calls?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using `XMLHttpRequest` quite a few times in a page. I manually construct the url e.g.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {  
    if (http.readyState === 4){  
        //dosomething  
    }  
};    
http.open('GET','/path/to/page.html?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4);  
http.send(null);
```

This is duplicated at least 4 times in the page. So I am looking how to refactor this.
How would I make this a separate utility function? Are there e.g. varargs in `javascript`?
How would the different request parameters would be passed to be appended to the url?
Please note: I am not asking about `JQuery`. The only reason that I am not asking/using `JQuery` is because I don't know it.
So please advice in terms of plain javascript

Comment: So you do not know how to make a function and build a string with variables?

Comment: @epascarello:What variables? In one case it is `a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4` in another it is `e=2` and in another no params. I need a varargs function right?

Comment: You could simply pass the data as an object. Variadic functions are possible too, but not necessary here.

Comment: @Cratylus: Why don't you simply pass them as one string in one parameter?

Comment: @Bergi:You have a point there. But it seemed cleaner to pass the properties separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define functions in JavaScript and thus make commands/procedures reusable. For example, you could create a function which accepts an object of `key -> value` mappings for the data and a callback which should be called once the response was received:

```
function make_request(url, data, done) {
    // initialize XMLHttpRequest object here

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {  
        if (http.readyState === 4){  
            done(http.responseText); // call callback
        }
    };

    // build query string / URL
    // this should be moved in its own function
    var kv = [];
    for (var prop in data) {
        kv.push(encodeURIComponent(prop) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[prop]));
    }
    url = url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + kv.join('&');

    http.open('GET', url);
    http.send(null);
}
```

This would then be called like so:

```
make_request('/path/to/page.html', {a:1, b:2, c:3}, function(response) {
    // do something with the response
});
```

You can make the function even more general by letting it accept parameters to configure the method ('GET' or 'POST'), the data to send in the request body, an error callback, etc.
The more general you make it, the more complex the logic usually becomes.

[**Learn more about functions.**](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html)

On the other hand, if you find yourself constantly making requests to the same URL and handling the response always the same way, it makes sense to create another function, which just accepts the data to be sent and makes the request to the URL.
For example:

```
function update(data) {
    make_request('/path/to/page.html', data, function(response) {
        // do something with the response
    });
}
```

Then you just have to call

```
update({a: 1});
// or
update({b: 2});
```

There is a tradeoff between avoiding code duplication and having code duplication. If you make the same request at 100 different places in your code, then it's worth while to create an extra function. If you just do this like five times, then probably not. Of course this depends on how much code would be duplicated.

---

To answer some of the question:

> How would I make this a separate utility function?

In technical terms, you [define a function with `function funcName() {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Defining_functions) and put the logic inside there. For an example of the logic, see above.

> Are there e.g. varargs in javascript?

Yes. In each function you can access the special [`arguments` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). This is an *array-like* object with a reference to each argument passed to the function.

> How would the different request parameters would be passed to be appended to the url?

In any way you like! You could pass a string which is already formatted correctly, i.e.

```
"a=1&b=2&c=3"
```

or you could pass an object where the keys are the parameter names and the values are the parameter values and then build the query string dynamically, as shown above. You could also pass a nested array of the form

```
[['paramName', 'paramValue'], ...]
```

or an array of objects like

```
[{name: 'paramName', value: 'paramValue'}, ...]
```

and do the same. That's really up to you.

The primary goal is to reduce code duplication. Using arrays or objects to pass along data is something you cannot avoid. But building a query string from such data can be factored out into a function.

Comment: +1!This answer is very educational to me! Thank you! BTW we need `encodeURIComponent` in case of spaces etc right?

Comment: Spaces and any other character that would mess up the URL at this point (e.g. `=` or `&` in the value or name).

Answer (score -2):

You might consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - it abstracts a lot of this for you.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {  
    if (http.readyState === 4){  
        //dosomething  
    }  
};    
http.open('GET','/path/to/page.html?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4);  
http.send(null);
```

Becomes:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/page.html',
    data: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
})
.done(function(r) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: @Bergi I did; this question is asking to cover a lot of already-covered ground with no clear benefit. Leveraging an existing, well-tested cross-platform library is a much better move than rerolling it all yourself.

Comment: The OP said NO jQuery, hence why @Bergi asked you if you read it! lol

Comment: @epascarello I'm aware; it's just not useful to cover already-covered ground with your own code when something well-tested already exists. The fact the OP doesn't know jQuery isn't a good reason to write their own XHR lib.